# Normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, parameter-estimation

X and Y are positive continuous random variables that are approximately normally distributed with E(X) = 50, sd(X) = 6 and E(Y) =30, sd(Y) = 4.

Pr( X/Y > 2) is equal to
I'm not sure how to do this. WOuld this just be Pr(X)/Pr(Y)>2? Do I need to apply continuity correction? I'm a bit lost. The possible answers are
0.023

0.159

0.238

0.460

0.841

Comment: Hi there! How are X and Y related? Are they independent? Moreover, I suggest being a little more precise when describing the problem. Also usage of TeX could help the readability.

Comment: This is all the information that is given. So I guess we can assume they are independent.

Comment: Your usage of Pr needs to be defined.   Density function - maybe, distribution function - no.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Since we're talkingabout normal distribution, wouldn't Pr just denote cdf?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do something like:
$$\mathbb{P}[\frac{X}{Y} > 2] = \mathbb{P}[X > 2Y, \ Y > 0] + \mathbb{P}[X < 2Y, \ Y < 0]$$
which yields:
$$\mathbb{P}[\frac{X}{Y} > 2] =\mathbb{P}[X - 2Y > 0, \ Y > 0] + \mathbb{P}[X - 2Y < 0, \ Y < 0]$$
then you should need something to argue $Z = (X - 2Y) \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where possibly $\mu = -10$ and $\sigma^2 = 10$.
Be careful: the fact $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is not trivial with the information you provided! For example, if $X$ and $Y$ happen to be jointly Gaussian, you get Z is Gaussian. Same with independence. In general, that is NOT true!

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't it be 1-0.8413 though?

Comment: Ok, to be fully correct. You should divide between the two cases $Y<0$ and $Y>0$ when multiplying into the inequality! I was really sloppy there and did only for $Y>0$ :D sorry